# How do i fix InvalidoperationException when querying EF code first database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Query:

```
var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email.Equals(username) && u.Password.Equals(password));
```

Error:

```
Local = 'db.Users.Local' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

Detailed error message:

> Message = "The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of D...
>   Source: ""entityframework"
>   StackTrace:StackTrace = "   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)\r\n   at System...

Comment: Where did you put your code? Nothing's wrong with the query but I'm guessing you are putting it in a wrong place.

Comment: Side node: It is bad practice to store the password in the database; store a cryptography hash of the password, preferably SALTed.

Comment: The thing is it was working fine until i moved my project from my documents to c: drive. I don't know if that may have caused the problem.

Comment: @DSid this error can be also happend if you have a wrong entities configuration or mapping! I think something mess between your releationships. is the database at this point exists or it is should be created at this query?

Answer (score 0):

you can set `MultipleActiveResultSets=true;`in your connection string

you should pay attention to the following in the error message

o`r if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads` concurrently.

```
yourcontext context = new yourcontext();

var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email.Equals(username) && u.Password.Equals(password));
```

before using the context here you have to dispose the connection like